# How to find the distance between a point and a plane as a function z of x and y?

Tags: geometry

I know that the point-to-plane distance equation is:

$D=\frac{ax_0 + by_0 + cz_0 + d}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$

(while $(x_0,y_0,z_o)$ is the given point).

That's fine if I have a plane equation of the form:

$ax + by + cz = d$

But what if I have the plane equation of the following form:

$z = -\frac{a}{c}x - \frac{b}{c}y + \frac{d}{c}$

How do I extract $a,b,c,d$ variables?

I know that I can multiply by $-c$ and get the equation in the first form, but I have the coefficients $\{-a/c \space ,\space -b/c \space, \space d/c\}$ replaced by actual numbers... So I don't know what $-c$ actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{c}x + \frac{b}{c}y + z = \frac{d}{c}$$

put $a^\prime = \frac{a}{c}$, $b^\prime = \frac{b}{c}$, $d^\prime = \frac{d}{c}$ and $c^\prime = 1$ you will get:

$$a^\prime x + b^\prime y + c^\prime z = d^\prime$$

---

You may see now that multiplying with a constant does not change the form of the equation. You do not need to know what $-c$ actually is.

You could also say, there are only three degrees of freedom when you define a 3-d plane (you only need three parameters, not four).

---

Written by [StackExchangeStrike](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/164061/sextus-empiricus?tab=profile)